# What is causing the reference error?

Tags: jquery

In this statement, I have an else statement that creates the missing property.

```
var suitcase = {
    shirt: "Hawaiian"
};

if(suitcase.hasOwnProperty(shorts) == true){
    console.log(suitcase.shorts);
}else{
    suitcase.shorts = "Filipiniana";
    console.log(suitcase.shorts);
}
```

But, I am still getting a ReferenceError.

```
ReferenceError: shorts is not defined
```

What is wrong with this code? I will appreciate any feedback :)

Comment: Thank you @RajaprabhuAravindasamy it does it! My code works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.hasOwnProperty` would expect a string/symbol as its parameter.

```
suitcase.hasOwnProperty("shorts")
```

The above code would work for you. You can read about `hasOwnProperty` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the shorts parameter in quotes. Needs to be a string.

```
suitcase.hasOwnProperty('shorts')
```

And you could also omit the redundant 'true' comparison in the first 'if' statement, since the hasOwnProperty() method will return the boolean value you are looking for.